# Medalha Copidesque concedida mas não aparece

Tags: bug, status-intencional, medalhas

Eu não sei se é bug mas parece-me que sim, ganhei hoje a medalha [Copidesque](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/49/copy-editor) mas não apareço no quadro da medalha, nem ela aparece no [meu perfil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/7210/jorge-b).

Entretanto a medalha apareceu, logo a seguir a ter deito esta pergunta, mas demorou 3 horas é normal?

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

<kbd>[image: http://imgur.com/HWRw2PL]</kbd>

Comment: Não sei se por coincidência ou não acabou de aparecer a notificação e a medalha ;)

Comment: http://geradormemes.com/media/created/tt220u.jpg

Comment: @Math já obtive a medalha há umas horas...

Comment: Bem vindo ao seleto clube dos copidesquistas :)

Comment: Eu obtive em 20 dias :D Nem tinha me tocado como é difícil p/ os demais :)

Comment: pô, @big, é covardia vc se comparar com os demais :P (vide: meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4331)