# Por que demora a aparecer a medalha?

Tags: suporte, medalhas

Galera não sei se está bugado... Faz algumas horas que eu acabei o desafio do eleitorado de medalha de ouro. Apareceu já como ganha, porém, não aparece no perfil a medalha.

Comment: Eu vejo a medalha no seu perfil

Comment: [Paciência você deve ter](http://s2.quickmeme.com/img/bb/bb9e43ab5aa33d4624bc764c783dba9fe5bab8b1299b364169f0d8582e809fe6.jpg)

Comment: Aqui as vezes demora quase uma hora para aparecer na aba superior :/

Comment: Scripts que calculam se o objetivo da medalha foi alcançado rodam de tempos em tempos, por isso existe um _delay_ entre você alcançá-lo e recebê-la de fato, mais detalhes aqui: [How long does it take for badges to be awarded? How are they generated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1716/229289). Se alguém quiser elaborar uma resposta com base nessa será bem vindo.

Comment: Relacionado: [Medalha Copidesque concedida mas não aparece](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4333/3117)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A maioria das medalhas são concedidas depois de um tempo. Seja porque a situação pode mudar, seja por otimização. Algumas demora apenas 5 minutos, outras ocorrem uma vez por dia, quase sempre de madrugada.

Até que atinja 24 horas que deveria ser concedida considera que está dentro da normalidade.

Também cuidado para avaliar se deveria receber a medalha, algumas depende de interpretar corretamente o texto. Especialmente a [eleitorado](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/951/101) muitas pessoas acham que é uma coisa e é outra.

Já recebeu a medalha.

Comment: Obrigado @Maniero♦ vi que apareceu de manhã! Valeu mesmo!